# SQL - Delete most recent duplicate records

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group, sql-delete

I've a table `Order` i my Oracle DB. Somehow the insert job ran twice and created duplicate records with only difference in timestamp:

| ID | NAME | ITEM | DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Ric | POTATO | 06-07-21 12:35:27.048000000 PM |
| 2 | Ric | POTATO | 06-07-21 12:35:27.048100000 PM |
| 3 | Ashley | KALE | 06-07-21 12:35:27.049000000 PM |
| 4 | Ashley | KALE | 06-07-21 12:35:27.049100000 PM |
| 5 | Adam | WATER | 06-07-21 12:36:27.050000000 PM |
| 5 | Adam | WATER | 06-07-21 12:36:27.050100000 PM |

Now I want to remove the most recent duplicate records.
How to create a query to delete the records where timestamp is latest for `(Name, Item)`?

Answer (score 2):

Provided that the column `NAME`, `ITEM` and `"DATE"` (you'd better not use
*reserved words*) are **unique keys** you may use following query

```
DELETE tab
 WHERE (NAME, ITEM, "DATE") IN
       (
        WITH del AS 
        (
         SELECT ID,
                NAME,
                ITEM,
                "DATE",
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY NAME, ITEM ORDER BY "DATE") AS rn
           FROM tab
         )  
       SELECT NAME,ITEM,"DATE" 
         FROM del 
        WHERE rn > 1
       );
```

This *guarantees* that for each combination of `NAME`, `ITEM` only the row with the *first* "DATE"  (rn = 1) preserves and all other will be deleted.

This query works even if there are keys with triplets or rows without duplication.

The unique key on  `NAME`, `ITEM` and `"DATE"` is important only to make the query  *deterministic*.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
delete from orders o
    where o.date > (select min(o2.date)
                    from orders o2
                    where o2.name = o.name and o2.item = o.item
                   );
```

Or if you want to use `not exists`, you can delete rows for which there is an earlier row:

```
delete from orders o
    where exists (select 1
                  from orders o2
                  where o2.name = o.name and
                        o2.item = o.item and
                        o2.date < o.date
                 );
```

Only the "first" row doesn't have an earlier row.